# Communicating between nearby mobile devices in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, bluetooth

I'm using a Web App for this particular application, and I'm wondering if there's any way, in JavaScript, to communicate with a nearby device running the same Web App?

The closest I can seem to find would be establishing a Bluetooth connection, but from what limited docs I can find it seems to be all about communicating with specific Bluetooth devices.

For instance, when specifying the filter for which devices to search for, how can I specify "a device running my Web App"? Is this even possible at all, or should I just give up now and go back to using a data connection with a server being in the middle?

Comment: A data connection to a server may be your best bet for the moment. Caniuse shows Web Bluetooth JS API isn't implemented in any major browser at the moment :( http://caniuse.com/#search=bluetooth

Comment: I'm aware it's currently behind an experimental flag in Chrome (which, if I had to pick a mobile browser to target, it would be that one), but I'm hoping that'll change in future. I guess ideally I'd offer both options, thereby allowing users to not require a data connection for this interaction.

Comment: Have you considered going down the Cordova route? You may be able to use a plugin such as this one https://github.com/bcsphere/bluetooth to access the native Bluetooth API using web technologies.